# Duplicating updated row on another table via trigger in mysql

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have two tables (A & B).
I want to duplicate a row from `Table A` to `Table B` when a value of a column in `Table A` is equal to `x`, how would I do that using a trigger?
`Table A` is constantly updating, via query in my vb.net program, until such time that a column in `Table A` equals to `x`, I want to copy that row into `Table B`, not via another query on vb.net but via mysql database trigger.
Any input would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for mySQL. I've tried it out.

```
CREATE TRIGGER `tableA_AUPD` AFTER UPDATE ON `tbla` FOR EACH ROW
begin   
    IF (NEW.fldx = 'x') THEN
        INSERT INTO tblb (fldb0,fldb1,fldx) VALUES(NEW.flda0,NEW.flda1,NEW.fldx);
    END IF;
end
```